# app was rejected because it did not apply MFi?

Tags: ios, app-store

My app mainly operate in wifi environment, through wifi to connect to an external wifi chip（MXCHIP-EMW3162),and transmits and receives data from wifi chip.

Resolution center gave me some advice to fix:

**Please either revise your Info.plist to include the UISupportedExternalAccessoryProtocols key and update your Review Notes to include the PPID # - or remove the external-accessory value from the UIBackgroundModes key.**

The first was rejected, UIBackgroundModes been removed, and then reviewed again, but still are in the same reasons for rejection,and I don't know what PPID.

In addition, APPLE has given me this advice:
**Additionally, your app must be authorized by MFi to use the desired hardware. If you are not yet in the MFi Program, you can enroll at MFi program.**

So I must be register MFi to pass review it?

Comment: see this link may be helps you https://forums.estimote.com/t/struggling-with-app-approval/449

Comment: thank @Anbu.Karthik,this Q & A I have read,His answer is **close Background Modes**,this way I have tried, I don't have any Background Modes in Info.plist,and tried this method, the re-submitted for review,APPLE rejected on the same reason

Comment: check are your removed your tick mark  in your background mode in target-->Capabilities-->background modes

Comment: YES,background modes is OFF,I had a confirmed.

Comment: then ask your query to apple for clear information for what the purpose of reject , those are given the clear information about updated rejection

Comment: thank you @Anbu.Karthik,I have already appealed to the apple.

Comment: Can someone explain to me, why Apple Review tells we (who develop app communicating with external accessory) MUST be in MFi, when officially, this is NOT TRUE ???  https://mfi.apple.com/MFiWeb/getFAQ.action#4-0

Answer (score 0):

PPID means the chip which your using ..The hardware merchant need to register his hardware device with apple will provide bundle id to chip hardware merchant from then u can get PPID... Hope so it will usefull..